# How to find the names of all tables created in the last SQL statement using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table

I have some code like the following:

```
$import = "CREATE TABLE foo..."; // an SQL import containing some CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, etc.
$result = $mysqli->query($import) or die ($mysqli->error);
```

How do I find the names of all the tables that were created in the last SQL query (i.e. the `$import` statement)? I was wondering if there was a special way in MySQL to do this, rather than just searching the statement for `CREATE TABLE`, which is kind-of a dirty hack.

Comment: don't know if there is another way. try getting the list of tables before and after the query and compare it.

Comment: @bansi Hmm yeah, I was thinking perhaps there could be something like `insert_id`, but for tables... guess I was a bit too optimistic on this one.

Comment: if you write the query, you should know

Comment: @Dagon I'm just showing a static query here for argument's sake, but in reality it would be from an SQL import file, so very dynamic in nature.

Comment: ugly regular expression?

Comment: you can select all the table from data base, and order them by date ASC, is it any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `information_schema.TABLES`

```
$time = time();

//create tables here  
...

select table_name, create_time 
from information_schema.TABLES
where create_time > $time
where table_schema = 'andomar'
order by CREATE_TIME desc
```

Comment: `where table_schema = 'andomar'` why you have this section

Comment: andomar it the database name

Comment: oh you made this name, i was already confused with the question, the way he ask the question, i think this answer is  +1